# MapKit, annotation and addSubview duplicate

Tags: swift, xcode

I implemented signing under annotations with the title. I did it with addSubview and label. I do not understand why the names are duplicated after the next reading of the points. The points themselves load correctly, the problem is only with the title.

screen:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6phGQ.png

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }
  
        let identifier = "Annotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
       
   
            annotationView!.isEnabled = true
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
            annotationView!.displayPriority = .required

 
        } else {
           
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
          
        }
        
        let detailAnnotation = annotation as! WaypointsAnnotation
 
        
          if (detailAnnotation.type == "Waypoint") {
   
              let imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: -15, y: -15, width: 30, height: 30))
              let label = UILabel()
              label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 1, width: 60, height: 30)
              label.textAlignment = .center
              label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
           
              label.text = annotation.title as? String
              label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
              imageview.addSubview(label)
            
         
              annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "point8")
              annotationView!.addSubview(imageview)
             
   
          }
         
      
        let rightButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        
        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didClickDetailDisclosure(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                   annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
      
        return annotationView
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls dequeueReusableAnnotationView to try to recycle a previously used `MKAnnotationView`. Then, regardless of whether you recycle an annotation view, you add a label and an image view.

If you are recycling a previously used annotation view, it will already have a label and image view attached to it. Each time you recycle an `MKAnnotationView`, you are adding an additional image view and label to it. Don't do that.

You should put the code that adds the label and image view inside the `if annotationView == nil` statement. That way you will only add an image view and label to an annotation view the first time you create it.

Instead of creating a generic `MKAnnotationView` and customizing it, you might want to create a custom subclass of `MKAnnotationView` that already has the label and image view fields attached to it.

Comment: Ok, I gave a label and image view to annotationView == nil statement and it works (not duplicate), but now on reloading each pin has a different title. The first time load it, it is ok.

Comment: You need a way to get to the existing label and image view to change it when you recycle it. That's why I suggested creating a custom subclass of MKAnnotationView. It would have outlets to the custom fields you've added. You'd try to fetch a recycled one. If you get one, you'd just set its label's text and image view's image. If not, you'd create a new one and do the same.